# How to invoke a stepFunction who's ARN is in the Input

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a StepFunction (Parent) that needs to invoke another StepFunction (Child).  I want to pass the ARN to the child step function as input to the child but doing so throws the following error

```
Invalid Arn: 'Invalid ARN prefix: $.StateMachine.child_ARN' (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArn; Request ID: 53d74c73-a33d-48c4-bf56-6001629c40e8; Proxy: null)
```

The child function definition is;

```json
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution",
  "Parameters": {
    "StateMachineArn": "$.StateMachine.child_ARN",
    "Input": {
      "$.input": "$.ExecutionInput"
    }
  },
  "End": true
}
```

And the parent's runtime input to the child is;

```json
{
  "StartTime": "2023-03-11T14:05:42.010Z",
  "Region": "us-west-2",
  "ExecutionInput": {
    "orderID": "1234qwerasdfzxcv"
  },

  "StateMachine": {
    "ProcessAlert_ARN": "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:123456789:stateMachine:child"
  }
}
```

If I change the Parameters for the child function to be; `arn:aws:states:us-west-2:123456789:stateMachine:child` it invokes successfully ... but I need to variablelize it.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `.$` to keys whose values have JSONPath substitutions, e.g. `StateMachineArn.$`:

```json
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution",
  "Parameters": {
    "StateMachineArn.$": "$.StateMachine.child_ARN",
    "Input": {
      "input.$": "$.ExecutionInput"
    }
  },
  "End": true
}
```

When a key has no `.$` suffix, the State Machine execution interprets the value literally - hence the error message.  The relevant docs are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-stepfunctions.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters).